# c# Open Windows 8 Application by url posted on facebook

Tags: c#, protocol-handler

I'm creating a Metro Application that allows you to share some content.
At this moment It's possible to share an url (e.g http//www.stackoverflow.com) on facebook.

What I actually want is to invite people (through facebook) to click on the shared link. When they click on the link I would like my application to start up and that it navigates to a certain page in the application.

e.g I have a food application and would like to share a specific restaurant on facebook. When a facebook friend clicks on the link, the food application would start up, he would navigate to that specific restaurant.

Is this possible and how can i do this?

p.s I added a protocol to "Declarations" on the manifest but than I'm stuck.

Comment: You do understand this would only work for people running Windows 8.  Why don't you display content that everyone can see?  This really depends how your application works and even if it supports being started to display specific content.

Comment: I do understand it will require Windows 8. Later I will expand the application to Windows Phone but atm only as a windows 8 app.
Do you haven an idea to "make" such an URL?

Answer (score 0):

you can share – only – 6 different types of data.

1. Bitmap: a bitmap represented by a stream of bytes. This one is provided by the system when you share a screenshot;
2. Html: text on the HTML format;
3. Rtf: text on the RTF format;
4. StorageItems: items which implements the IStorageItem interface. It seems to be media items located on a physical drive;
5. Text: raw text sharing;
6. Uri: you can share link with this format;

Data is shared through an object called the DataPackage.  In this article, we’re going to divide Share Source and Share Target into two separate sections.

and for lunching metro application from your website please follow this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh781489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

and if you want to share your application link try this www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=